# How to comment in Visual Studio Code like in Notepad++?

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++, comments

In Notepad++ I always select the part I want to comment then right click -> block comment. But I can't do it in Visual Studio Code.

Is there a way (or extension) to do this?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + A. You can also assign your own keyboard shortcuts in settings.

Comment: Shift+Alt+A on Windows at least.

Comment: Ctlr + /   ==> comment line or block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL + /`

Is used to line or block comment.